# Stop Android Studio Tool Tip Flashing?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio tool tips are helpful but they appear so quickly and flicker so fast as I type. I feel like my eyes and nervous system will be fried very soon from overstimulation. It is like someone is talking in my ear and poking me in the back constantly while I work.

The tool tips also cover text I'm trying to read.

I don't want the tool tips to go away. I just want a reasonable chance to fix problems before Android Studio badgers me about a million different things.

I've tried increasing the tool tip delay to 1200 ms through the UI. I even read some way that allowed me set it longer than that. I set it to 5000 ms. Nothing seemed to increase the delay. Even restarting Android Studio after making the changes.

I'm on a Mac.

What can I do to calm the Android Studio tool tips down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could change them from "balloon" to "sticky balloon" so you would have to make them go away yourself. Not sure that would be preferable though.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/notifications.html

Mostly they are easy to get back once you know they are there. Usually by going to the left of the line with the warning tick-mark. you'll get a place to click to inquire as to what's going on. Least that's how I don't go all ADD on them. Where else do they grab your attention?